# Three.js Attach a label on the side of sphere

Tags: rotation, three.js, geometry, label

I have 300 small spheres which represent human genes with relative 3D position. The question is: I need add a label to each sphere (label suppose attached on the side of sphere)to show the basic gene information, and the label can rotate with sphere when use rotates the camera.
I cannot find any example online, please help!

Any suggestion is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You can create a parent object/ use parenting, something like  parent = new Three.Object3D();
Then you do parent.add( sphereMesh); and parent.add( labelMesh) where labelMesh is a PlaneGeometry.

Also see examples here: (labeled Geometry for example)

http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/

Comment: I tried but only get one label appears, and also the label doesn't very close to sphere. Thanks a lot for you suggestions!

Comment: well, there is a complete example where edges and vertices are numbered with labels. If you can't reproduce a similar result with the existing code base, just keep on trying :)

Comment: Thank you GuyGood, by following your suggestions, I made it work.<pre><code> var texture = new THREE.Texture(context );
                texture.needsUpdate = true;
                var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( {map: texture, overdraw: true, side:THREE.DoubleSide} );
                
                var plane = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(130, 20 );
                var text = new THREE.Mesh(plane,material)
                
                text.applyMatrix( new THREE.Matrix4().makeTranslation(95, 0, 0 ) );
                
                sphere.add(text);</code></pre>

Comment: cool, glad it works. :) Would be nice of you to accept the answer but you dont have to, of course. Have a nice day^^